# Question on finite fields

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

I was curious about this question:

Let $p$ be a prime, and $d \geq 1$ and $K$ is a field of $p^d$. How many proper subfields does $K$ have?

All I know if that a finite field has order $p^n$, where $p$ is the characteristicc of $K$ and $n:[K:\mathbb{Z}_p]$. But not sure how that helps find the amount of subfields.

Comment: $\mathbb F_{p^n}^{\times}$ is a cyclic group of order $p^n-1$. If $\mathbb F_{p^m}$ is a subfield, then its multiplicative group is of order $p^m-1$ and is a subgroup of $\mathbb F_{p^n}^{\times}$.  So, $p^m-1$ must be divisor of $p^n-1$. What does that tell you about $m$ and $n$?

Comment: $K$ is a Galois extension of $\Bbb{Z}_p$ with a cyclic Galois group $C_n$. By Galois theory the subfields are in 1-1- correspondence with the subgroups of the Galois group. The cyclic group has a unique subgroup of order $m$ for all divisors $m\mid n$. There are other ways to reach the same conclusion (see Dilip's comment).